# "Command not found" when running guest additions. xubuntu 14.04

Tags: virtualbox, xubuntu

Guest additions iso is mounted. The next logical step is to run:

```
sudo ./VBoxAdditions.run
```

Then it shows:

```
sudo: ./VBoxAdditions.run: command not found
```

This is getting irritating as I've read countless threads and followed the "correct" methods. I've tried on two different vboxes, one 32 and one 64.

Comment: Make sure you're in the Guest Additions folder `cd /media/cdrom/` then run `sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`

Comment: Go to directory where your `VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` file exist & then run `sudo sh ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run `

Comment: Inserting the guest additions CD ROM does not add anything in /media/cdrom/, nor does it show any errors. It just doesn't work. Vanilla install, nothing special.

Answer (score 3):

Browse to your guest additions folder. It is in your `/media/<username>/*` folder. Here's a screenshot to that:

[image: 1]

Now, type the command:

```
cd DRAG AND DROP THE VBOX GUEST ADDITIONS FOLDER HERE
```

<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Now, run

```
./VBoxAdditions.run
```

<kbd>Enter</kbd>

If there are any errors stating `Permission Denied`, then type:

```
sudo ./VBoxAdditions.run
```

<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure your VM is prepared to make kernel modules. This is copy-paste friendly.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install build-essential module-assistant
sudo m-a prepare
```

Loom for the CD name by running `sudo ls /media/`. It should show up as `VBOXADDITIONS` or something similar.

Then simply run

`sudo sh /media/<<<CD NAME>>>/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`

or

`sudo sh /media/<<<username>>>/<<<CD NAME>>>/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`

Answer (score 0):

If the VBoxAdditions.run is not set to be executable, you'll also get the same error.

```
$ sudo chmod a+x VBoxAdditions.run
```

`+x` make the program executable. 
`a` is for all user. `u+x` might work. Try it first.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

After that try to run the program again.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing the full path instead of `./VBoxAdditions.run`. I was using this command
    `sudo /media/$USER/VBox*/VBoxLinux*.run`
The same error would appear "command not found". So I looked up the folder where my VBox folder is and I saw the full name of the file and I typed that in the command and it worked.

```
sudo /media/$USER/VBox*/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved by making sure i was in VBox_Gas_6.1.12 as my working directory.   This will not work if your working directory is in the root cause you VBoxLinuxAdditions.run file is not in the root, but in the VBox_Gas_6.1.12 (A cd addition)

To go to this Vbox_Gas,

Click on the devices on your virtual machine window, then click add guest additions.
On the new window that pops up click the VBox_Gas folder(it should be under file system) this will take you to the right directory.

Then click on File on top of the Menu bar of VBox_Gas directory, click Open Terminal Here. This will open the terminal whose working directory is in the VBox_Gas cd directory. Then type and run the sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run